# How to check whether the collection is sharded or not in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I Wrote

```
db.runCommand({enablesharding : "database"})

db.runCommand({shardcollection : "database.coll_1",key : {_id :"hashed"}})
```

And how to check is collection sahrded or not?
Maybe exist some function that I do not know.
Plese help me!

Comment: `db.printShardingStatus()`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connect to mongos and run the following:

```
use config;
db.collections.find( {_id: "db.colname" , dropped : false } )
```

if collection is shared it'll appear there along with it sharding key

Comment: I've had situations where the above command returns a valid object, implying that sharding is enabled on the collection, but sharding is not enabled on the collection, as shown by .stats().

Instead, you can check for:
`use databaseName;
db.collectionName.stats().sharded`

Comment: @Scott It might be that the collection doesn't contain enough data, to start splitting it to chunks, and store it in different shards.
Say A is the minimum amount of data, starting from which your collection is sharded, unless your dataset size is larger than A, you will have all the data on that first same shard

Comment: In the cases we were seeing, the collection definitely had enough data to move chunks, but even before the first chunk split or move happens, the collection should still advertise itself as sharded, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 17):

I Use the following :

`use dbname
db.colname.getShardDistribution()`

Outputs the sharding distribution if it's sharded, and `Collection dbname.colname is not sharded` if it's not.
Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getShardDistribution/) for more details.

I also use @Scott's comment aswell (`use databaseName; db.collectionName.stats().sharded`) but i prefer the `getShardDistribution`, it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

db.printShardingStatus()

gives metadata also

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can run this to list all not sharded collections

```
db.getCollectionInfos().forEach(function(c) { if(!db.getCollection(c.name).stats().sharded) { print(c.name)} })
```

or this to print sharded ones

```
db.getCollectionInfos().forEach(function(c) { if(!db.getCollection(c.name).stats().sharded) { print(c.name)} })
```